# Format numbers in an Indesign table similar to Excel

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, tables, formatting

I'm working on a document that has a small pricing table in it and I'd like to know if there is a way to set my table cells to automatically format my numbers the same way that Microsoft Excel does:

[image]

As it stands now, I have to manually enter the `$` and `,` in each price and I'm more of the type that likes to let the computer do the little things where I can.

I'd like to be able to simply enter my values like this:

[image]

Then have indesign automatically format them to this:

[image]

I created the table inside Indesign and I am inputting my numbers directly, not importing or linking from another source.

Possible?

Comment: Are you doing a data merge or inputing the data directly into InDesign?

Comment: @AndrewH Direct input.  I'll edit to clarify

Comment: InDesign has limited table functions compared to Excel. However, this can be done via scripting or by runnig a few GREP queries.